When can template.content return null?
Note: I asked this question in the WHATWG repo, but the issue was closed almost instantly with a reason stating something like "this sort of question is better suited for SO".
The WHATWG specs say about the <template> .content getter:

The content getter steps are to return template's template contents,
if the template contents is not a ShadowRoot node; otherwise null.

A non-null value can be gotten quite trivially:


let template = document.createElement("template");
console.log(template.content); /// #document-fragmnt



But I can't find an example where template.content would return null. Can someone provide such an example?

By default,  document fragment in content property exists

@YuvarajM how does it answer to my question when content returns null?

It's been added when declarative Shadow DOM got implemented, but I'm not sure in what circumstances you could get access to the <template> element in that case, since AFAIK it never really reaches the DOM.

@Kaiido exactly, that's why I confused by spec.

"I asked this question in the WHATWG repo, but the issue was closed almost instantly" - try it in bug report format. "The .content getter of a template never can return null, please fix the spec". In small print: "…or show me a counterexample" :-)

To be clear though, even if we web-authors can't access it doesn't mean it would be wrong to spec it like that. At least the specs can access it and this method would need to return null in that case.

@bergi I like your style, I'll do that :)

You're right that this might be a leftover bit of spec, from the days when the declarative shadow dom spec wasn't the "streaming" variety. In that world, the template would actually get added to the DOM, and it was important not to allow access to the .content before it was converted to a shadow root. I'm not sure there's a way to have a null .content at this point. Perhaps you could point me to your WHATWG issue and I can re-open it?

@MasonFreed I wrote you in email (I described in detail that issue there) and you can check it here
